# Question about Markov Chains

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

The following question is taken from the book titled **"Probability models  for Computer Science"** written by Sheldon M. Ross.

Question:

A particle moves along **n + 1** vertices that are situated on a circle in the following manner. At each stage the particle moves one step that is either in the clockwise direction with probability **p** or in the counter-clockwise direction with probabiity **1-p**.

Starting at a specified state let **T** denote the time of the first return to that state. Now how to find the probability that the particle has visited all the vertices by time **T**

Comment: What is your question?  What are your thoughts?  We're not really looking for posts that are just the statement of an exercise-style task.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First suppose that $p \ne 1/2$, and let $q=1-p$. If the first step is clockwise, then the problem is a gambler's ruin problem, and the chance of success (visiting all nodes) is
$$\frac{1-q/p}{1-(q/p)^{n+1}} \,,$$
See [1] or [2], section 17.3 or [3]. If the first step is counterclockwise, then  the chance of success  is
$$\frac{1-p/q}{1-(p/q)^{n+1}} \,.$$
Thus overall, the probability that the particle has visited all the vertices by time $T$ is
$$p\frac{1-q/p}{1-(q/p)^{n+1}}+q \frac{1-p/q}{1-(p/q)^{n+1}} \,. \tag{*}$$

If $p=1/2$ then again there is a reduction to a gambler's ruin problem, so by [1] or  [2] Section 2.1, or [3],  the answer is 1/(n+1). This answer can also be obtained by taking the limit as $p \to 1/2$ in $(*)$.

[1]  Feller, W. 1968. An introduction to probability theory and its applications, third edition, Vol. 1, Wiley, New York. Chapter XIV

[2] https://www.yuval-peres-books.com/markov-chains-and-mixing-times/

[3] Grinstead, C. and L. Snell. 1997. Introduction to Probability, 2nd revised edition, American Mathematical Society, Providence. Chapter 12.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the idea. Let the vertices be $v_0,\ldots,v_n$, where $v_0$ is the origin and the vertices are arranged in clockwise order. The first step is either clockwise or counterclockwise — let's say clockwise. Then the probability you're after is the probability that you reach $v_n$ before you reach $v_0$, starting at $v_1$. This is random walk on a line, so you should be able to analyze it.